# jQuery doesn't respond: JSFiddle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-events, jsfiddle

Here is my [JsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/cjFUf/1/). I'm testing that jQuery works, but it doesn't. Have I made any mistakes? I have checked documentation of jQuery and everything seems to be okay. What's wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //insert code here
    alert("this will flre when the DOM is loaded.");
});
```

Comment: You did not load the jQuery library. Look at the left panel. http://jsfiddle.net/cjFUf/7/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the library first as given in the image below

[image]

Then you can call jQuery as below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("All is well");
});
```

Check out this live fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mayooresan/TTu3C/

Comment: thanks works! But I have another problem. I put those in my html file  <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){ 
   alert('hi')
  });
  </script> 
and it doesnt respond...

Comment: You don't have to manually import them in html when u use jsfiddle.

Comment: but I want to import these jsfidle document into html

Comment: Once you import it to your local html file, manually add them to the file.

Answer (score 3):

You need to choose the jQuery library on the left. It let jsFiddle know what kind of library or framework you want to load.

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the JS file in the left top.

this will do.

Edit: Updated Version of JSFiddle supports "FRAMEWORKS & EXTENSIONS" under "JavaScipt" Section. There user may select JQuery Version.

I have included and updated fiddle.

```
Fiddle Link:http://jsfiddle.net/MarmeeK/cjFUf/51/
```

Or see the Image below for more clarity.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to load the library... on you left hand side of the fiddle.. you need to choose the framework you want to choose..in your case it is jquery

```
Frameworks & Extensions
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/cjFUf/4/)...